# bcp end of file error for utf-8 text file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp

Our current setup uses bcp to load .txt files (UTF-16) into sql server (2012).

We have changed the encoding of these files from UTF-16 to UTF-8. This saves our processing times (when exporting from the source system).

However, upon this change. We now encounter an end of file error.

error = [microsoft][sql server native client 10.0]unexpected eof encountered in bcp data-file

[image]

This is what is in our bcp error file.

#@ Row 2, Column 1: Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file @#

This is one of the smallest files we have. It contains the Extract time.

[image]

I have tried the following bcp command:

```
[server].master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp "aida_ods_nl_prd.imp.t_aidaextracttime" in c:\temp\aidaextracttime.txt -fc:\temp\bcp_format_files\aidaextracttime.fmt -q -c raw -w -f2 -r\n -t -s [server]\sql2012 -ec:\temp\bcp_errors\aidaextracttime_errors.txt'
```

Does bcp support utf-8 in sql 2012?
If yes,
What am I doing wrong? Is the row terminator -r/n not correct>

```
        @bcp_parms
    ==========
    -q     - set quoted_identifiers on
    -C RAW - codepage - no conversion from one codepage to another
    -w     - performs the bulk copy operation using Unicode characters
    -F1    - First row is the 1st row (no column headers)
    -F2    - First row is the 2nd row (row 1 has column headers)
    -r\r   - row terminator (override default with a carriage return)
    -T     - connect to SQL Server with a trusted connection
```

Comment: If you specify the Code Page (with the `-C` switch) does it work? Note that SQL Server 2012 itself does *not* support UTF-8; that was added in SQL Server 2019.

Comment: I have the -C switch, doesn't work. About SQL versions I did find this online but not sure what it means. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3136780-utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sql-command-in-sql-server-2014-sp2-fc6706f2-3ceb-0dc2-425e-af4da42a45a1?msclkid=ab05a3fba9e111ec98ef05afd9f71f06

Comment: It means you have to be using SQL Server 2014 SP2 or later. The `-C` switch has always been there, allowing you to select encodings for various OEM code pages, but UTF-8 support was only added with code page `65001` in 2014 SP2. Although Microsoft's own documentation is sometimes contradictory saying, _Versions prior to version 13 (SQL Server 2016 (13.x)) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding). Versions beginning with 13 can import UTF-8 encoding to earlier versions of SQL Server._

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I came to the same conclusion yesterday. I think UTF-8 requires bcp utility version 13 onwards and SQL server 2014 onwards

Comment: i suggest using a better text editor/viewer than notepad. try view the file with something like Notepad++ or UltraEdit. Get a better view of hidden characters to make sure of the row terminator.